# Facing problem getting output for sentiment analysis the code always labels all articles as 0.0 irrespective of there type

Tags: natural-language

from textblob import TextBlob

from newspaper import Article

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics'

article = Article(url)

article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp

text =article.summary
print(text)

blob = TextBlob(text)

sentiment = blob.sentiment.polarity # -1 to 1

print(sentiment)

Comment: This question is very general/seems to ask for debugging a snippet of code. However, programming questions are off-topic on Cross Validated and are better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Also, do you expect the wikipedia article about mathematics to express a sentiment?